# I need to find a pool that supports cpuminer

Tags: mining-pools, cpu

I've been to mine with cpuminer with lots of different pools but nothing works!!! I only made it to mine litecoin on litecoinpool.org, but I need bitcoin! Which pool would you recommend?

Comment: Are you aware how incredibly obsolete CPU mining is for Bitcoin? I can't imagine any pool having shares so infinitesimal that you could ever hope to earn one.  Or do you have some other special purpose in mind?

Answer (score 1):

None exist. CPU mining had been impossible for years now. You better stop wasting energy and the life time of your computer.

Comment: I mean. I wouldn't use the word impossible, because *technically* there's a chance...

Comment: I never recommend lotteries to people, but in this case a lottery is almost a sure win compared to that. Also I'm not sure what the mining software and mining pool software actually do if you're not producing shares. I doubt they will keep wasting time on you to keep sending you new work. So even technically I doubt it would work.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of getting a few satoshis to play with without taking out my credit card / visiting a physical vendor?